# Open and close divs with jQuery, less verbiage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still learning JavaScript/jQuery and I'm trying to open and close divs with the least amount of verbiage, I'm trying to break free of the habit of repeating myself because its easier to code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(function () {

    $('#section-two, #section-three').css('display', 'none');

    $('.section-opener').function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      var target = $(this).data("target");
      var $target = $(target);
  
      $('.section').not($target).stop(true, true).css('display', 'none');
      $target.stop(true, true).css('display', 'block');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="section-opener"><h4>Section One</h4></a>
<div class="section" id="section-one">
  <p>I am inside section one</p>
</div>

<a href="#" class="section-opener"><h4>Section Two</h4></a>
<div class="section" id="section-two">
  <p>I am inside section two</p>
</div>  

<a href="#" class="section-opener"><h4>Section Three</h4></a>
<div class="section" id="section-three">
  <p>I am inside section three</p>
</div>
```

I'm not having any luck as currently none of it is working.

Comment: it's not quite clear to me what you're asking?

Comment: What is `$(this).data("target")` supposed to read, I don’t see any corresponding data? What are you calling `.stop` for, if there weren’t any animations started in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very confusing and it looks incorrect as well.

When you mention closing and opening it seems like you mean show and hide instead of what is normally considered "closing", i.e. `</div>`

Also, it appears you are using JavaScript to set the initial display where you should be using CSS:

```
<style>
  #section-two, #section-three{
     display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Your `.stop()` and `.function()` and `target`, `$target` all serve to make your code very difficult to understand. I suggest reading some tutorials to understand the basics, because it appears you do not understand the code you're writing.

Also, perhaps you are looking for `$().show()` and `$().hide()` functions? Those perform the `display:block` and `display:none` shortcuts.

I created a jsfiddle which does what I *think* you wanted:

http://jsfiddle.net/48xuvL6y/1/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.section-opener').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = $(this).data("target");

        $('.section').hide();

        $(target).show();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.section {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is what I was looking for. I have used the code I provided a few times before, it was actually someone on this site that provided me with it.